# Bind Parameter causes error with fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm still having some issues with binding parameters.

I created a simple password hash check and now I'm trying to do it with bounded parameters to prevent sql injection.

Here is the original which works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='{$_POST['Email']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash_pwd = $row['Password'];
$hash = password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hash_pwd);
```

And here is my attempt at binding parameters:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email= ?"); 
$result->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']); 
$result->execute(); 
$result->store_result(); 

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$hash_pwd = $row['Password'];
//hash checks password
$hash = password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hash_pwd);
```

The latter returns "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()"

Comment: You can't use `fetch_assoc()` with prepared statements. You need to use `bind_result()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) class has no method `fetch_assoc()`, only [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

For example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email= ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']); 

// bind_result() method takes references to variables for storing a results.
$stmt->bind_result($password);

// fetch() return true, false or null
$return = $result->fetch();

if ($return) {
    echo $password; // Contains a value of first column
}
```

The [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) is a method of [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email= ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']); 

$stmt->execute();

// Get the instance of mysqli_result:
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row    = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($row) {
    echo $row['password'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking online and found a similar solution but my syntax and structure were just wrong. This helped me understand it a lot better.